# create docker image for python web service in windows 10

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm a complete beginner in Docker and I want to create an image for a web service app I have made in Flask . My web service folder is called MovieFlix and contains my `webservice.py`, a folder called templates with HTML templates inside, and a `.git` file which I do not know if it is necessary to include. This is my first time using Docker and I will list my steps below.

I have made a Dockerfile file with no extension inside a folder I named DockerFolder.
Inside the Dockerfile, I wrote a few steps as following:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04 //create base image 
MAINTAINER bill <bill@gmailcom>
COPY //this is where I want to copy my web service I believe I should put the complete path of MovieFlix folder?
CMD //I do not know how to run the container or my app 
RUN // I think that here I should install Python and the libraries I need for the Python app 
USER bill 
EXPOSE 80 tcp
```

I would appreciate your help with guiding me to create the Docker image and run my Python app. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does your Flask service work properly without Docker? Can you show us how you run the app now (outside of Docker)?

Comment: @mabergerx It's a simple flask app . 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000) Then I just click on the url while my program is running and I can close it by ctrl + C

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER bill <bill@gmailcom>
# Here we copy your API directory to the container
COPY ./MovieFlix /MovieFlix
# Copy the requirements and install
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
# Expose your port
EXPOSE 80
# Set the working directory to your main file
WORKDIR "/MovieFlix"
# Run the Flask app like you usually do
CMD ["python", "webservice.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Note that you need to put your running of Flask app into a `CMD` statement and not a `RUN` statement, as you want your container to run the app when you run the image and not when you build it.

Comment: host has to be 0.0.0.0 ? Because in my flask app i have 127.0.0.1

Comment: No, it can be localhost or you can even leave it out to have the default Flask behaviour

Comment: I do not understand this line in your code . Why include movieflix twice ? 
# Here we copy your API directory to the container
COPY ./MovieFlix /MovieFlix

Comment: Here we copy the dir from your local system to the container [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: in COPY ./MovieFlix /MovieFlix I get COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder664580866/MovieFlix: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but the Docker images I've made I started from a Python image. So my Docker file looks something like this:

```
FROM python:3.x

MAINTAINER Me

COPY . /app #Copy whole directory where the docker file is to /app directory, I've also seen /usr/app but I guess it's just personal preference.

WORKDIR /app #Switch to the directory you've copied the app to. So you're working from the directory where your app is, makes running files easier.

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt #Install required packages

CMD ["python", "./Movieflix/webservice.py"] #Run Python and my python file
```

Starting with a python images saves you having to install it yourself whichever base you're using, although running on the standard python image available from docker hub is quite large. If you're able to get it running on python3.x-alpine it would be a lot smaller but alpine doesn't come with a lot of preinstalled packages.

If your entire app is in the ./Movieflix directory, put the docker file in there and you can remove ./Movieflix from the CMD line.

I have assumed that the directory you start in only include stuff for your app and not a load of other stuff you don't want to copy to the image.

The `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` line will install packages required for your app but you do need to have created the "requirements.txt" file. If you're using a virtual environment you can with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

It's also worth looking at the Docker documentation here about EXPOSE if you haven't already as EXPOSE doesn't actually publish the port for you to access it via localhost (if thats what youre trying to do).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

If you don't want to include any files, its worth using a .dockerignore file. Works similar to .gitignore.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Personally I never include git files or any virtual environment files. Also don't include anything you don't want others to see.

Hope that helps

Comment: so I copy the DockerFolder where I have my dockerfile inside the folder where I have the html templates and the flask app ?

Comment: Yes I think so. Lets say you have everything you need to run your app in the directory MovieFlix, then you'd put the dockerfile in MoveFlix as well. Then the line `COPY . /app` will copy the whole MoveFlix folder.

Comment: When you come to building the image you'd navigate to  the MovieFlix directory using a command prompt and run `docker build -t mywebbapp:v1 .` which will use the dockerfile to build the image. Alternatively, you can user `docker build -t mywebbapp:v1 <pathtoMovieFlix>`